# How to save Order Status Message in Craft Commerce using frontend form

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, order, status

It's easy enough update the order status from the frontend using:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="commerce/orders/updateStatus">
<input type="hidden" name="orderId" value="{{ order.id }}">
<input type="hidden" name="orderStatusId" value="{{ order.orderStatus.id }}">
```

But I'm wanting to add a message to go with the status. Any pointers? It looks like the message is part of the Order History model, not the Order Status model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating an order from the front end would not be possible unless the user has update/manage order permissions.

As for the message it is simply a `message` post param that you send along with the status ID.

Comment: Thanks Luke. Something must have been awry as I'd tried that but it's now working.